# Add-On Dev: Attaching data to scene objects without Blender properties

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I just found out that it's possible to attach variables to scene objects without using Blender property types. For example..

`bpy.data.scenes[0]["MyData"] = MyData`

This data is also saved and loaded with the *.blend file just as with property types.

Is this safe to use? Is it restricted in any way? Can I attach anything, or just certain types? I tested it with a list of `int`, and it worked, but I had to convert the loaded value back into a list after loading, with `to_list()`.

I'm curious as to why I've rarely seen anyone doing this. Especially since it seems to be the only way to attach basic list types to scene objects (without defining the basic type inside of a property group, and defining that inside of a property collection).

One thing I can probably guess is that these would not support undo/redo functionality.

Appreciate any info on this

Comment: A lot of information there. Thanks!